# Invariants of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused as to what this question is actually asking. I understand that if A and B are similar $P^{-1}AP=B$

[image]

Comment: It's asking, for example, whether, if $A$ and $B$ are similar, it follows that $A^3-I$ and $B^3-I$ have the same rank.

Answer (score 0):

- $i)$

We have that

$$B^3-I=P^{-1}A^3P-I=P^{-1}(A^3-I)P.$$

Now use that similar matrices have the same rank.

- $ii)$

We have

$$B+B^5=P^{-1}AP+P^{-1}A^5P=P^{-1}(A+A^5)P.$$

Now use that similar matrices have the same trace.

- $iii)$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\3 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ and the similar diagonalizable matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\0 & 4\end{pmatrix}$.

- $iv)$

Same example of $iii).$

- $v)$

Using the linearity of trace and that similar matrices have the same trace we have

$$\mathrm{trace}(2B-B^T)=2\mathrm{trace}(B)-\mathrm{trace}(B^T)=2\mathrm{trace}(B)-\mathrm{trace}(B)\\= \mathrm{trace}(B)=\mathrm{trace}(P^{-1}AP)=\mathrm{trace}(A).$$